# discord.py preventing deletion of messages containing #start

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

so in the bot I'm making there's a loop which deletes any messages that don't say `#start` in a specific time. But I want it to delete any messages which contain '#start' AND anything else. So if I were to send `#start` on a discord server, the bot wouldn't delete it, but if I were to send a message that says `#start testing` it would delete the message. I'm not sure how to do this. This is what I've come up with:

```
while hour >= 12 and hour < 14:
   msg = await bot.wait_for_message(timeout=1, author=message.author)
   if "#start" not in msg.content:
      await bot.delete_message(msg)
   hour = int(time.strftime("%H"))
```

It says that `msg` doesn't have an attribute called `content` even though I can use it if i'm writing a message to a csv file. So any ideas? I'm all ears

Comment: `if msg and "#start" not in msg.content`, because sometimes `msg` will be `None`.

Comment: well that solved the second problem of me not knowing how to do msg.content. But the initial problem was in the first paragraph. I want messages that only say `"#start" in with no words afterwards, to not be deleted. Whilst any other messages are deleted.

Comment: `if msg and '#start' != msg.content:`. This will check that `msg` is not `None` and that it is not exactly '#Start'. All other messages will be deleted.